# Marshalling const std::string parameters

Tags: c++, .net, marshalling, unmanaged, managed

When I try to import the function

```
extern __declspec(dllexport)  void SomeNativeFunction(const std::string param1, const std::string param2);
```

defined and declared in `SomeNative.Dll` into a .NET console application using

```
class Program
{
        [DllImport("SomeNative", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        extern static void SomeNativeFuntion(string param1, string param2);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   
            StartEventHandling("param1", "param2");
        }
}
```

I get the error

*System.AccessViolationException' occurred in ManagedS7DosEventManagerClient.dll
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.*

Which is probably an indication, that I need to marshal the parameters correctly.

[This overview of default marshalings for strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings) unfortunately doesn't say anything about marshaling of standard library strings.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can't marshal a `std::string`, you need to do something different

Comment: i.e. change the interface of the unmanaged dll?

Comment: That's certainly the easiest option